# How can I apply different CSS styling for admin users in Concrete 5.7?

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

How can I apply unique CSS styles to a section of my Concrete 5.7 website just for admin users?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found is to apply a class to your `<body>` tag based on whether the user is an admin.

As of Concrete 5.7.5.6 the '*Administrators*' group has an ID of 3, so this code should work:

```
<?php
$isAdminUser = !empty((new User())->getUserGroups()[3]);
$bodyClass = $isAdminUser
    ? 'user-is-admin'
    : 'user-is-non-admin';
?>

<body class="<?= $bodyClass ?>">
```

Then you can just write your CSS like this...

```
.user-is-admin     .alert { }
.user-is-non-admin .alert { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make the assumption that the admin group has the ID 3, such code is error-prone. Better use the constant concrete5 defines:

```
$u = new User();
$adminGroup = Group::getByID(ADMIN_GROUP_ID);
if ($u->inGroup($adminGroup)) {
   ...
}
```

You could also get the group by its name, at least if you don't change it ;-)

```
$adminGroup = Group::getByName('Administrators');
```

The complete solution based on your code would then look like:

```
<?php
$u = new User();
$adminGroup = Group::getByID(ADMIN_GROUP_ID);
$bodyClass = 'user-is-non-admin';
if ($u->inGroup($adminGroup)) {
   $bodyClass = 'user-is-admin';
}
?>
<body class="<?=$bodyClass?>">
```

Comment: Hi Remo. Yes your code is more reliable, thanks, although it doesn't fully cover the original question. So perhaps I'll update my answer with your additions which are really helpful, thank you.